# numberOfBytesTransferred return 0 for Avplayer

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, avplayer

I am calculating the data transfer of the Avplayer while playing a Dash content. I am using the below code to get the access log.

```
    let accesslog: AVPlayerItemAccessLog? = player?.currentItem?.accessLog()
    var events: [Any]? = accesslog?.events
    let event = events?[0] as? AVPlayerItemAccessLogEvent
    print("Number of bytes received \(event?.numberOfBytesTransferred)")

    let byteData = (event?.numberOfBytesTransferred)! / 1024
```

Randomly event?.numberOfBytesTransferred shows 0, sometimes, it shows value as well. What is the standard procedure of doing this?

Comment: if your player start to seek on that time you get `0`

Comment: No, I am not seeking.. Its simple playback only.